# Can one browse Twitter on the web anonymously and avoid being forced to login to continue

Tags: twitter, account-management, anonymous

When reading anonymously in a browser on Twitter, there comes a point when Twitter forces you to login in order to continue.

Is there a way to continue without needing to login?

Answer (score 1):

#### No, you cannot

In order to browse [Twitter](https://twitter.com/) in your web browser **without restrictions**, you must login when prompted, or start another session.

Disabling `JavaScript` in your browser isn't a workaround.  Twitter now blocks access to browsers that have JavaScript disabled.

#### Other Options

In order to access Twitter anonymously, you will need to get the data through a method other than their website.  There are a number of approaches people use, some are pay-to-use, some not.

For example you could take a look at [nitter project on Github](https://github.com/zedeus/nitter) which does the anonymizing for you.